# Are there learning resources to drill my Dutch?

Tags: resource-request, self-learning, grammar, dutch

When I was learning English we used lots of exercises that were referred to as **use of English**, which help you train some particular grammar.

Now, I am learning Dutch and most of the exercises require me to finish the sentence as I wish or just answer questions correctly and adequately. But I would like to find a collection of drilling exercises (i.e book, website, software) to improve my grammar in a systematic way.

Does someone know good books or other learning materials that have these kinds of exercises with answers?

Answer (score 6):

There are a few grammar exercises at http://nl.ver-taal.com/grammatica.htm.

You can find a larger set of exercises on the website [Ik schrijf beter](http://ikschrijfbeter.nl/oefenen-grammatica).

You can buy books with grammar exercises, but it is also possible to create your own exercises by turning sentences from your reading materials into cloze tests and entering these cloze tests into a spaced repetition system such as [Anki](https://apps.ankiweb.net/). This approach has two advantages over grammar books:

1. You can pick sentences that actually interest you.
2. The tests you get wrong will be presented again with a short delay, whereas nobody redoes grammar exercises from a book ...

Answer (score 5):

Below are some resources for practicing your grammar skills in Dutch:

- [This](http://www.goethe-verlag.com/tests/EN/EN.HTM) is a set of 200 fill-in-the-blank quizzes that tests both vocabulary and grammar.
- [This](http://dutch.tolearnfree.com/free-dutch-lessons/) website seems like a very comprehensive guide for the whole language, covering everything from grammatical gender to more advanced nouns. [This](http://dutch.tolearnfree.com/cgi2/myexam/liaison.php?liaison=_grammaire_) is the page on the site dedicated to grammar exercises.
- Finally, [this website](http://home.scarlet.be/~rp148/gen/indexN.html) contains  quite a few Dutch grammar tests as well.

Answer (score 2):

I believe [Cambiumned](http://www.cambiumned.nl/) is used often on Dutch high schools.

One of the potential downside, which can also be an upside, is that this site is completely in Dutch. It is focused on people who are learning Dutch as their native language. If your Dutch is good enough, this is not really a problem however, and it can even help in that case.

One notable thing is that the spelling of verbs (*werkwoordspelling*) is considered as a part of spelling, not as a part of grammar (*grammatica*), as it is in most languages. Also, be sure to check some of the parts under style and then formulating, (*stijl*, *formuleren*), since they actually include more advanced parts of the Dutch language.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It is not what I had in mind, but it looks like a good website for other aspects of language learning.

Answer (score 2):

[BeterSpellen.nl](https://www.beterspellen.nl/) is a site where you fill in a daily test at three different skill levels (1F is primary school level, 2F is lower vocational or societal level and 3F is theoretical high school level).

You need to make an account and then you can choose to be reminded of the test daily. After submitting your answers you get detailed feedback (in Dutch). To get an idea of the type of questions, I made an account and the screenshots below give an indication of the questions (click to view full-size versions).

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To share, you could try Beginner Dutch app or StartFromZero_Dutch apps to familiarize yourself with the basic Dutch vocabulary.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shex.beginnerdutch
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shex.startfromzero_dutch